# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'ids', in kivymd

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I created a simple MDfieldwidget I am trying to reference the text but I got an AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'ids', in kivymd
here is my main.py file  (thanks in advance for your help)

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager


class LoginScreen(Screen):
    pass


class SecondScreen(Screen):
    pass


class LoginApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):

        users_name = self.root.ids.users_name
        my_label = self.root.ids.my_label
        my_label.text = users_name.text

        sm = ScreenManager()
        sm.add_widget(LoginScreen(name='Screen1'))
        sm.add_widget(SecondScreen(name='Screen2'))

        return sm


LoginApp().run()
```

here is my .kv file

```
<LoginScreen>
    MDScreen:
        name: 'Screen1'
        md_bg_color: (23/255, 31/255, 40/255, 1)

        MDCard:
            size_hint: None, None
            size: 320, 400
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}
            orientation: 'vertical'
            padding: '8dp'
            md_bg_color: (23/255, 31/255, 47/255, 1)
            elevation: 10
            spacing: 10

            MDLabel:
                text: 'LOGIN'
                font_style: 'Button'
                font_size: 45
                halign: 'center'
                size_hint_y: None
                height: self.texture_size[1]
                theme_text_color: 'Custom'
                text_color: (1, 1, 1, 1)
                padding_y: 15

            MDTextFieldRound:
                hint_text: 'enter username'
                icon_right: 'account'
                color_active: 1, 1, 1, 1
                pos_hint: {"center_x":.5}
                size_hint_x: None
                width: 220
                font_size: 16

            # MDSeparator:
            #         height: "1dp"

            MDTextFieldRound:
                hint_text: 'enter password'
                icon_right: 'eye-off'
                color_active: 1, 1, 1, 1
                size_hint_x: None
                width: 210
                font_size: 15
                pos_hint: {"center_x": .5}
                password: True

            MDTextField:
                id: users_name
                hint_text: "What's your name?"
                helper_text: "What your friends call you.."
                helper_text_mode: "on_focus"
                pos_hint: {"center_x": .5}
                size_hint_x: None
                width: 200

            MDRectangleFlatButton:
                text: 'LOGIN'
                pos_hint: {'center_x': .5}
                size_hint_x: None
                root_button_anim: True
                on_press:
                    # change direction to to non-movable
                    root.manager.transition.direction = 'left'
                    root.manager.current = 'Screen2'
        
            Widget:
                pos_hint_y: None
                height: 30


<SecondScreen>
    MDScreen:
        md_bg_color: (23/255, 31/255, 40/255, 1)
        name: 'Screen2'
        MDCard:
            md_bg_color: (23/255, 31/255, 47/255, 1)
            padding: 10
            elevation: 10
            orientation: 'vertical'
            spacing: 25
            pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, "center_y": .5}
            size_hint: None, None
            size: 340, 400

            MDTextButton:
                text: '< Back'
                padding_x: 0
                custom_color: (244/255, 246/255, 214/255, 1)
                pos_hint: {"center_y": .1}
                root_button_anim: True
                on_press:
                    # change direction to to non-movable
                    root.manager.transition.direction = 'right'
                    root.manager.current = 'Screen1'

            MDLabel:
                id: my_label
                text: f'Hello {my_label.text}'
                # halign: 'center'
                pos_hint: {'center_x': .5}
                size_hint_y: None
                font_style: 'Body1'
                theme_text_color: 'Custom'
                text_color: (1, 1, 1, 1)

                font_size: 20
                height: self.texture_size[1]
                padding_y: 15

            Widget:
                height: 10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple problems with your code:

- You are trying to copy the text from a `MDTextField` to a `MDLabel` before the user has a chance to enter text into the `MDTextField`. Also, the `ids` have not yet been assigned in the `build()` method.
- Your are trying to access `ids` using `self.root`, which is the `ScreenManager`, but the `ids` are defined in the `LoginScreen` and `SecondScreen`. See the [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.lang.html#ids).

You can solve these problems by doing the name copy when the user enters the name, and by correctly using `ids`. In your `kv`, use the `text` property to trigger the copy:

```
        MDTextField:
            id: users_name
            hint_text: "What's your name?"
            helper_text: "What your friends call you.."
            helper_text_mode: "on_focus"
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .5}
            size_hint_x: None
            width: 200
            on_text: app.set_user_name(self.text)
```

Then add the `set_user_name()` method to the `App`:

```
def set_user_name(self, name):
    my_label = self.root.get_screen('Screen2').ids.my_label
    my_label.text = name
```

And, of course, remove these lines from `build()`:

```
    users_name = self.root.ids.users_name
    my_label = self.root.ids.my_label
    my_label.text = users_name.text
```

Another approach, if you do not want the erase the text that is already in the `MDLabel` is to use the `MDRectangleFlatButton` as the trigger. In that case, the `kv` for the MDTextField becomes:

```
        MDTextField:
            id: users_name
            hint_text: "What's your name?"
            helper_text: "What your friends call you.."
            helper_text_mode: "on_focus"
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .5}
            size_hint_x: None
            width: 200
```

which is your original code. Add the trigger for the `set_user_name()` method to the `Button`:

```
        MDRectangleFlatButton:
            text: 'LOGIN'
            pos_hint: {'center_x': .5}
            size_hint_x: None
            root_button_anim: True
            on_press:
                # change direction to to non-movable
                root.manager.transition.direction = 'left'
                root.manager.current = 'Screen2'
                app.set_user_name(users_name.text)  # trigger name copy
```

And the `set_user_name()` method must be adjusted to:

```
def set_user_name(self, name):
    my_label = self.root.get_screen('Screen2').ids.my_label
    my_label.text += name  # append name rather than over-write
```

Comment: Thank you very much it worked.. But it has an issue, when it shows on the second screen it, erase the word before it.

Comment: This is my MDLabel code:
                **id: my_label
                **text: f'Hello {my_label.text}'**
                **pos_hint: {'center_x': .5}**
                **size_hint_y: None**
                **font_style: 'Body1'**
                **theme_text_color: 'Custom'**
                **text_color: (1, 1, 1, 1)**  ...So what I mean it doesn't print the hello along user input. Please how do I fix this.. Thank you in advance

Comment: Thanks alot, it good now.. I would love if you could recommend resources for me to understand this concept.. Thanks, I appreciate all the help..